Allow comments to "bump" a question in the "active question" list
When logging into the site, I see the so-called "Interesting Questions", containing recently added questions, recently modified questions and recently answered questions; but I have the impression that recently commented questions are not there, nor in the "Hot" tab, although they should (according to my use case).

Is it possible to add recently commented questions to the (user's) homepage?
Is this dependent of the entire Stack Exchange list of sites?


My use case:
I just had a problem: I wanted to see a list of tables, sorted according to their number of entries, in my SQL-Server database.
I looked for that here on the website and stumbled on this question, which contained this very interesting answer, which I immediately upvoted.
However, while doing what was explained in the answer, I saw something I didn't understand (the background colour of the results), so I decided to add a comment, asking for more information. As a result, a notification will be sent to "[the answerer]", but now it seems that this person has not visited the website over more than a month, heavily reducing the possibility of getting an answer.
Arguably, if by reason of my adding a comment to an answer, the question would be moved to the top of the "active questions" list, it would be more likely someone would see it and reply to my comment.

I don't think comments are important enough to bump a question, is your usecase that "Someone asked for clarification about an answer in a comment, so it should be made visible to other users in case they can answer"? Why not simply ask a question if you want people to have a look at it and answer?

You can still use bounties to attract attention. Or just ask your own question.

@AbdulAzizBarkat: thanks for the terminology, I didn't know this was called "bumping" a question. Is there somewhere a list of actions/conditions, leading to a bump of a question?

The reason you are downvoted here is not because you need to improve your question. It is because people disagree with your feature-request. Personally I don't think a new comment warrants the question being shown again.

@Dominique See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped

I think one problem is that not all comments would be "good" for bumping the Q&A. Not all comments are clarifications or informational like yours. Some are coming from review queues, which can be either be the template ones or custom ones, and in both cases, should those bump the Q&A? Some are useless comments like "thanks!" or "it worked for me in 2024" Basically, the system needs some criteria for "this comment should bump the Q&A".

@GinoMempin: so you are saying that, in case a comment is added which is not automatically generated or which is not useless (as far as this can be detected), it could be a good idea bumping the question? Thanks a lot!

I'm saying that bumping a Q&A in the feed means it is asking for attention. But not all comments deserve everyone's attention.

@Dominique wait, so you wanted the list of things that cause a bump because you actually wanted to bump that post? Please don't do such things (misuse edits to bump post / ask a follow up question), if you really want your question answered just ask a question...

This question is similar to: Best way to draw attention to someone else's good question?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@KarlKnechtel Ehhh, it's more "I want to seek clarification on a specific answer, and I believe that someone other than the author could provide that clarification, but it does not rise to the level of an entirely new question"

@RyanM Sure. But the best way to do that is still to draw attention to the question. Someone else can edit the existing answers, or write a new one, to produce something that addresses the underlying concern.

You wanted someone other than the author of the post to answer the question you posted in a comment. That's exactly what the site has questions for.

Comments are meant mainly to request changes or clarifications to a post. As such, they are best handled by the author of the post, as they are best suited to add any missing detail, or to clarify meaning.
Any other user can safely ignore the post until the comments are addressed. With edits, which would then bump the question on the "active" list.
It makes no sense to bump a post (so it receives more attention from everyone) because of an action that is meant to request attention from a single user.
Even the example you present makes this patently clear: you posted a comment asking the answerer for more information. The answerer is the one who can add that information to the post, any other user would be ill-suited to add extra information to the post.

As an aside, one shouldn't perform edits just to bump a question (like you attempted to do here). Depending on your specific needs, either post a new question, or post a bounty.

??? Your last phrase makes completely no sense: the answerer might know the answer on my comment, but other people might too: asking questions which can be answered by anybody is the whole idea of this website!

(!!!) If you want to ask a question that anyone can answer, then what you want to post is a "question", not a "comment". Comments are meant to address one specific post, and information missing on a post can only be added by the post author. (See "When should I leave a comment", on the relevant Help Center article.

I can put it simply why I personally would never want something like this.
Comments happen non-stop. It'd turn any feed into white noise basically. The only questions with comment changes you should really have an interest in are the ones with comments directed at you, and those appear in your inbox.
